# Bidirectional relation/communication between Windows Form and Class

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I would like to have some sort of communication between a Windows Form and another class.

More specifically: between Form F and Class C

1. User clicks on button on F
2. This triggers a boolean to change in C
3. Some stuff happens in C (C has a running process)
4. A activates a method of F that changes some picture placed inside F

I don't see how this can be done without giving both an instance of the other object...

Thanks to anyone who can (and will :D) help!

Comment: Think about using Events? F Subscribes to an event within class C...

Comment: Yes [Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx) are the primary means of communication in WinForms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding...

1. F has an instance of a C class.
2. F is subscribed to some sort of event in C Class that triggers a picture change on Form F.

Comment: Thank you! Looking back it might have been a stupid thing to ask. I just never made something with winforms before...

Answer (score 1):

Additional to @Alex simple and lovely solution that completely fits here, for more complicated cases in the future, you may consider using [**Mediator Pattern**](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/mediator) as it is designed to solving such problems:

> We want to design reusable components, but dependencies between the
>   potentially reusable pieces demonstrates the "spaghetti code"
>   phenomenon (trying to scoop a single serving results in an "all or
>   nothing clump").

And take a look at an implementation using C#:

- [Mediator Design Pattern in C#](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/mediator/c-sharp-dot-net)